# Сдала экзамены и зачеты по дисциплинам или из таких дисциплин?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать, сдала экзамены по дисциплинам или из дисциплин?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это какой-то составной экзамен, и он состоит из нескольких дисциплин, то в этом смысле можно сказать "из". Но крайне желательно чтобы там было слово "состоящий": *"экзамен, состоящий из таких-то дисциплин"*. Да и то это будет некое исключительно разговорное упрощение, поскольку речь и тут идет речь об экзамене (состоящем) ***из*** испытаний ***по*** таким-то дисциплинаи.

Во всех остальных случаях, конечно, только ***"по таким-то дисциплинам"***

Comment: вот же ведь) А я бы и не подумал, что можно как-то извернуться и найти возможность использовать «из» в этом контексте :)

Answer (score 1):

«Сдать экзамены из (с) чего» — это украинизм :). В стандартном русском языке правильным является управление «Сдать экзамены по чему»: [ЕГЭ по математике](https://ege.yandex.ru/mathematics/), например.

Comment: Не похоже на украинизм. Т.е. "с чего" - это да, по-украински, но откуда такое в русском? Думаю, что просто южнорусские диалекты.

Comment: @behemothus Ну, какие такие диалекты?.. Вспомните "Родную речь", все мы(старший контингент) читали отрывки из воспоминаний А.Ульяновой(Елизаровой): ""Возвращаясь из гимназии, Володя рассказывал отцу о том, что было на уроках, из чего его спрашивали и как он отвечал. Так как обычно повторялось одно и то же - удачные ответы, хорошие отметки, - то иногда Володя просто, быстро шагая мимо кабинета отца по проходной комнате, через которую шла его дорога к себе, наверх, скороговоркой на ходу рапортовал: "Из греческого пять, из немецкого пять".

Comment: Предметы, конечно, менялись; иногда звучало: "Из латыни пять, из алгебры пять", но суть была одна, получалась обычно одна отметка - 5.

Comment: Чем головы забиты у нынешней, типа, интеллигенции? Первые школьные знания выветриваются...

Comment: @behemothus, в украинском "із" и "з" (аналог русского "с") — это, по сути, один предлог, употребление которого регулируется исключительно благозвучием: формальные правила там есть, но по сути это именно так.

Comment: @Варяг-91, если вы правы и это употреблялось, значит, это сильно устаревшая норма. Никогда не видел такого в более или менее современных источниках.

Comment: @AndrePolykanine, я знаю украинский. Вопрос не в том. Не всякое же совпадение объяснять влиянием соседнего языка, если нет реальных фактов такого влияния в конкретном случае?

Comment: Варяг-91, браво. Хороший пример. Интересно, это реальная речь образованных жителей Симбирска? Получается, некий архаизм. То-то я удивляюсь, что мне это неправильность слух особо не режет. Но, впрочем, вариант с диалектами или говорами это не отменяет.

Comment: @behemothus Это реальная речь людей, имевших отношение к гимназическому и вообще к любому образованию в дореволюционной России. Это, как мне представляется, сленг, который смело можем назвать литературным языком тех времен.